# Outer join in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a `posts` collection in the following format:

```
{
    reqID: Int32
    chatID: Int64
    messageID: Int32
    visits: Int32
}
```

I also have a `user` collection which has an array field named `visits`:

```
visits: [
{
    chatID: Int64
    messageID: Int32
    lastVisit: Int64
}
]
```

I want to select every `post` from the first collection where the desired `user` has not visited it in last 24 hrs. Well this is an outer join, but MongoDB has limited support for outer joins only using `$lookup` which is appropriate only for simple foreign key lookup. Are there any tricks which can help me to find what I want internally in DMBS?

Comment: This is also called an anti-join or an anti-semijoin and you are right, it's often done in SQL with an `OUTER JOIN` and an `WHERE .. IS NULL` condition.

Comment: which field do you use to join two collections?